# Disabling all horizontal scrollable charts

Tags: flutter, syncfusion, syncfusion-chart

I'm working with the [syncfusion_flutter_charts](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts) package.
I have almost a perfect result, my only problem being that because the chart has the possibility to scroll horizontally in the package (I have no use for it on my app), whenever I want to scroll vertically on my screen and I tap on the chart to start my scroll down/up gesture, the screen doesn't move because the chart think I want to scroll horizontally even when there is no data on the chart.

I made a [video](https://streamable.com/dzlqjm) to sum up my problem.
In the video, you can see that when I tap anywhere on the screen, I can scroll down/up my view, but when I tap on one of the charts, it's not possible.

How can we totally disable the horizontal scroll ?

I searched on the [documentation](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/overview) but I still don't have any solution as for now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```dart
IgnorePointer(
    ignoring: true,
    child: // your child here
)
```

Comment: It could be a solution, but doing this, disable the longTap() that display the information of the chart.

Answer (score 1):

The swipe gesture is prohibited purposefully while user interactions are enabled in the following scenarios:

1. Crosshair or trackball enabled with single tap as activation mode
2. Zooming or panning enabled with modes other than the selection zooming

To overcome the reported issue scenarios, kindly upgrade the package version to the latest version below.
https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts/versions/19.1.54+1

Comment: Hi @dineshkumar-kovalan , thanks you for your reply.

Even after updating the syncfusion_flutter_charts dependency to version 19.1.54+1, and having a trackball enabled with single tap as activation mode I'm still not able to scroll on my view when i'm taping on the charts.

How can I achieve this ?